# How to include nested relationships?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

At http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes

Articles belongs to an author. Articles have many comments. Comments belongs to a user.

Trying to understand how to include nested relationships. Take for example: https://www.foo.com/articles?include=comments

You would expect:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: "articles",
      attributes: { ... },
      relationships: {
        author: { ... },
        comments: [{ ... }, { ... }],
      },
      ...
    },
    { ... }
  ]
  included: [
    {
      author: { ... },
      comment: { ... },
      comment: { ... }
    {
  ]
}
```

Now lets say, you wanted to include the users who wrote those comments. https://www.foo.com/articles?include=comments.user

Should the response look like:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: "articles",
      attributes: { ... },
      relationships: {
        author: { ... },
        comments: [{ ... }, { ... }]
      },
      ...
    },
    { ... }
  ]
  included: [
    {
      author: { ... },
      comment: { ... },
      comment: { ... },
      user: { ... },
      user: { ... }
    {
  ]
}
```

Should `users` (users who wrote the comments) also be in the `relationship` node, or just in the `included` node?

If in the `relationship` node. Should `user` be nested inside `data.relationships.comments`? How would that look?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Top Level](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level) documentation, the `included` field should be an array of [Resource Objects](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-objects). This means your `included` field should look like this:

```
"included": [
    {
        "type": "author",
        "id": ...,
        "attributes": { ... },
        "relationships": { ... }
    }, {
        "type": "comment",
        "id": ...,
        "attributes": { ... },
        "relationships": { ... }
    }
]
```

Also according to the [Relationships](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships) documentation, it should (when side-loading data) contain a [Resource Linkage](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) `data` field which will contain either a single [Resource Identifier](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-identifier-objects) in the case of a `belongsTo` relationship, or an array of resource identifier objects in the case of a `hasMany` relationship.

`belongsTo` resource identifier:

```
"relationships": {
    "author": {
        "links": { ... },
        "data": { "type": ..., "id": ... }
    },
    "comments": {
        "links": { ... },
        "data": [
            { "type": ..., "id": ... },
            { "type": ..., "id": ... }
        ]
    }
}
```